# Weird Oracle error: missing right parenthesis if not using parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The following query

```
select 
    (to_char(MIN(RECIEVED_TIME) -
    interval '0' minute,'YY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) 
from 
    TableName 
where 
    SRC_IP is null and DST_IP is null
```

In SQL Developer returning the error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   Cause:
>   Action:
>   Error at Line: 9 Column: 16

If I just add the `()` parenthesis at the start and end it is returning the correct value

```
(
   select 
       (to_char(MIN(RECIEVED_TIME) -
       interval '0' minute,'YY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')) 
   from 
       TableName 
   where 
       SRC_IP is null and DST_IP is null 
)
```

It is returning the value

```
15-07-28 12:00:00 AM
```

**Whats the problem here?**

**Edit**

If I remove the carriage return after `-` its working fine like below

```
select 
    (to_char(MIN(RECIEVED_TIME) - interval '0' minute,'YY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'))  
 ......
 ......
```

but if I keep the braces at the start and end don't have to worry about carriage return ...I think its a problem of `SQL Developer`

Comment: why do you do `-interval '0' minute`? Why do you wrap your statement into brackets?

Comment: Actually I forgot to edit the interval value it is not '0' its having some value.. and its a requirement

Comment: impossible to reproduce... what did you use to execute the query ? didn't you select just a part and try to execute it via toad for example ?

Comment: @StevenBENET, yeah SQL Developer and I've Mentioned that in my Question

Comment: There's something else going on here. [This SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aad8e/1) demonstrates that the statement executes just fine. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: The errors says "Error at Line: 9 Column: 16" but you only posted 7 lines of code, is this just a snippet?

Comment: @BrokenCrust, The question was edited that's why the error lines are not getting matched

Comment: @BobJarvis, I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: I think its not an Oracle database issue..problem seems to me in SQL Developer

Comment: Perhaps you should help SQL Developer know where the end of the query is with a statement terminator (a semi-colon).

Comment: Regarding @BrokenCrust's question: in the original version of this question, the query consisted of only three lines. So we're back to "which line is line 9"? Next: your query works perfectly well in 11g as demonstrated by the SQLFiddle in my earlier comment. Thus, the problem seems to revolve around other code which you haven't included in the question.

Comment: @BobJarvis, Yeah but actually I have commented out all the other lines and after the BrokenCrust Comment I have tested the query in a new window also...